# Windows 10 Update Stuck in Automatic Repair Loop

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

When updating my Windows 10 computer with [2020-12 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 20H2 for x64-based Systems (KB4592438)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4592438/windows-10-update-kb4592438) on restart I get Preparing Automatic Repair which seems to do nothing.

After a few restarts I got dropped into EFI shell only and could not get into Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many searches of people with this issue I was not looking forward to possibly having to do some involved recovery.  Some searches took me down the path of making recovery media or doing a BIOS update but I didn't end up doing that but that led me to looking at BIOS settings.

Since I was ending up in the EFI shell googling around took me to this post: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/fixed-stuck-in-efi-shell-nothing-is-working-cant-boot-cant-return-to-bios-msi-read-last-reply-for-fix.1973592/

The solution mentioned in the post was turn off fast boot in BIOS settings.  I did that and now on restarting I could get back into windows and a few days later was able to install the update (with fast boot still off).

I realize this answer could be better but I don't remember exactly the steps I took but this was the gist of it and I wanted to share what turned out to be an extremely easy fix.